# Golang Heroku Web app AWS S3

Tags: html, go, heroku

I am trying to modify a CLI based golang program to a one working on Heroku (GUI). I want to read a file from AWS S3 and use it in the process() and getdomains() function. Need help with the S3 bucket connection and reading of file to put in place of "domains.txt"

Some functions from the Go program Snippet:

```
  package main

    import (
        "bufio"
        "bytes"
        "crypto/tls"
        "fmt"
        "io/ioutil"
        "log"
        "math/rand"
        "net"
        "net/http"
        "os"
        "strings"
        "sync"
        "time"
    )


    var Wordlist string = ""
    var int Threads, Timeout
    var Https, Strict bool = false, false

    type Http struct {
        Url, Num string
    }

  func getDomains(path string) (lines []string, Error error) {

    file, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    defer file.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)

    for scanner.Scan() {
        lines = append(lines, scanner.Text())
    }

    return lines, scanner.Err()
}

func Process() {


        urls := make(chan *Http, Threads*10) // parameters threads taken as input from html form
        list, err := getDomains("file name taken from html form")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }

        var wg sync.WaitGroup
        for i := 0; i < Threads; i++ {
            wg.Add(1)
            go func() {
                for url := range urls {
                    url.DNS()
                }

                wg.Done()
            }()
        }

        for i := 0; i < len(list); i++ {
            Progress := fmt.Sprintf("%d", len(list))
            urls <- &Http{Url: list[i], Num: Progress}
        }

        close(urls)

        wg.Wait()

        fmt.Printf("\r%s", strings.Repeat(" ", 100))
        fmt.Printf("\rTask completed.\n")
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Inside your `hello` handler use the `*http.Request`'s [FormValue](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.FormValue) method.

Comment: Nothing prints on the same page, If I make a submit button and another handler for the second HTML page where the variable values can be printed, how would that HTML code be?

Comment: To learn how to render values in your templates take a look at https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/ (same rules apply for `html/template`).

Comment: Here's an example: https://play.golang.org/p/X245hmGbAfb